# Matching embedded newlines in python regex

Tags: python, regex, multiline

What is the way to handle this? I have tried various permutations of strings, raw strings and (?is), re.DOTALL, but have been uniformly unsuccessful.

Following is a sampling of what I have tried:

```
>>> x="select a.b from a join b \nwhere a.id is not null"
>>> print (x)
select a.b from a join b 
where a.id is not null
>>> y=re.match("(?is)select (.*) from (.*) where (?P<where>.*)",x,re.DOTALL)
>>> y.groupdict()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'
```

Note have also tried:

```
    >>> x=r"""select a.b from a join b
 where a.id is not null""""
```

Same (incorrect result)

I have also tried with/without (?is) and re.DOTALL.

Note: if the embedded newline is removed from the tested string, then the match works perfectly:

```
>>> nonewline="select a.b from a join b where a.id is not null"
>>> y=re.match("(?is)select (.*) from (.*) where (?P<where>.*)",nonewline,re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
>>> y.groupdict()
{'where': 'a.id is not null'}
```

Comment: As soon as the newline is removed from the tested string, the groupdict() comes back perfectly. I updated the question to reflect this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you actually have a newline right before the `where` statement, and not a space.

**Your text:**

`"select a.b from a join b \nwhere a.id is not null"`

--------------------------------------------^

**Your regex:**

`(?is)select (.*) from (.*) where (?P<where>.*)`

-------------------------------------------^

Try something like this instead:

```
from re import *

x = "select a.b from a join b \nwhere a.id is not null"
y = match("select\s+(.*?)\s+from\s+(.*?)\s+where\s+(?P<where>.*)",
                                                            x, DOTALL)
print(y.groups())
print(y.groupdict())
```

Output:

```
('a.b', 'a join b', 'a.id is not null')
{'where': 'a.id is not null'}
```

Comment: Following up:  i removed the 'hard-coded' blanks and put in [\s]+ in their stead.

Comment: @javadba: I edited my regex in order to remove spaces from the matched strings